# How to show the details of the logged in user without the Request.QueryString[" "]; method in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I need to do is this:

Each user, when they log in, can see their details. For that, I have created a form called Shiko.aspx.

The code behind this form is:

```
public partial class Shiko : System.Web.UI.Page

    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                string idCard = Request.QueryString["id"];
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(idCard))
                {
                    Employee.DetailsDataTable table = Matrix.GetEmployeeById(idCard);
                    if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        System.Data.DataRow row = table.Rows[0];`

                        lblIdCard.Text = row["IdCard"].ToString();
                        lblPassword.Text = row["Password"].ToString();
                        lblEmri.Text = row["Firstname"].ToString();
                        lblMbiemri.Text = row["Lastname"].ToString();
                        lblGjinia.Text = row["Gender"].ToString();
                        lblDitelindja.Text = row["Birthday"].ToString();
                        lblPaga.Text = row["Salary"].ToString();
                        lblTelefoni.Text = row["Phone"].ToString();
                        lblQyteti.Text = row["City"].ToString();

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        // HERE IS THE PART OF THE CODE I NEED TO ADD
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that when the admin logs in and clicks on the Details link on his panel, using the QueryString it lets him see the details of that employer, but if he clicks on the NavigationMenu "Details" without using the query string it shows only an empty form with the names of each row ( I used labels in the form) but it doesn't populate the form with the details of the logged in user.

My question is, how to do that?

Comment: Are talking about asp or asp.net, your page name (Shiko.asp) is contradictory

Comment: I am talking about asp.net ( the aspx page)